# Remove element by ID in looping using onclick - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have fetch data (checkbox and text) from database and display it on a html form. The data were displayed by using looping. So, the problem is, I have delete button in the looping and when I delete, it will delete the whole data instead of delete the one I desired.

All HTML in foreach looping

```
<input type="checkbox" class ="checkbox" name="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" id="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" value="<?php echo $ans->correct; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?>/>

<input type="text" name="answer[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][answer]"  id="answer" class="" value="<?php echo $ans->answer; ?>">

<a class="md-btn-danger" id="remove" ></a>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#remove').click(function(){
        $('#answer').remove();
        $('#remove').remove();
        $('.checkbox').remove();
    });
```

it supposed to be the delete button only delete the selected one by the checkbox and text id

Comment: Please include all relative HTML, JS, etc when asking your question. This helps tremendously to the viewers, and will assist us [the viewers] when attempting to debug your code, and ultimately produce an answer(s)

Comment: I have edit the question. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data is dynamically added. Then don't use IDs because IDs should be unique

You should use class names on remove anchors. Then `remove` elements using `prev()` or `next()` function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.remove').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().remove(); //Remove input
    $(this).prev().remove(); // Remove checkbox
    $(this).remove(); // Remove this
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class ="checkbox" name="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" id="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" value="<?php echo $ans->correct; ?>" checked/>

<input type="text" name="answer"  id="answer" class="" value="answer">

<a class="md-btn-danger remove" >Remove</a><br>
<input type="checkbox" class ="checkbox" name="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" id="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" value="<?php echo $ans->correct; ?>" checked/>

<input type="text" name="answer[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][answer]"  id="answer" class="" value="<?php echo $ans->answer; ?>">

<a class="md-btn-danger remove" >Remove</a>
```

Or add parent element:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.remove').on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class ="checkbox" name="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" id="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" value="<?php echo $ans->correct; ?>" checked/>

<input type="text" name="answer"  id="answer" class="" value="answer">

<a class="md-btn-danger remove" >Remove</a><br>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class ="checkbox" name="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" id="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" value="<?php echo $ans->correct; ?>" checked/>

<input type="text" name="answer[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][answer]"  id="answer" class="" value="<?php echo $ans->answer; ?>">

<a class="md-btn-danger remove" >Remove</a></div>
```

Comment: It's only remove the button. The textbox and checkbox were not removed

Comment: Yes, it just did not work on mine, I follow yours but the remove button only get removed. The other two did not get deleted.

Comment: $(this).prev().remove(); //Remove input
    $(this).prev().remove(); // Remove checkbox

How do the code read one is for input and the other one si for checkbox?

Comment: Can you show your pure html code that is generated by PHP.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" class ="checkbox" name="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" id="correct[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][correct]" value="<?php echo $ans->correct; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?>/>

<input type="text" name="answer[<?php echo $ans->answerid; ?>][answer]"  id="answer" class="" value="<?php echo $ans->answer; ?>">

<a class="md-btn-danger remove" id="" ></a>`

Comment: This should work because same code is in snippet. Try adding parent element like div and then,in jQuery:- `$(this).parent().remove()` or attach event like: `$('.remove').on("click", function (....`

Answer (score 0):

check the heirarchy you have given as parentNode. You are removing the parent node which holds the whole data. So, give relation correctly. This might only be the problem. Otherwise it alright. If it does not work please share your bit of code containing that part.....

Comment: Hello sir, Please use comments for such short answers.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to give parentNode only one time instead of inside removeChild() method.

Comment: I can't quite follow with your suggestion